# Minimum possible order of a group with elements of order 1 to 5

Tags: group-theory

> If G is a group containing elements of order 1 to 5, then what is the minimum possible order of this group?

My answer: We know that the order of the elements of a group divides the order of group, so the minimum possible order of G would be the l.c.m of 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5 which is 120.

I just wanted to confirm if I am right.

Comment: The lcm of 1,2,3,4,5 is 60...

Comment: Uups! Yes, you are right.

Comment: jgon's answer is spot on, but I wanted to highlight an important step of the process.  Your argument shows that the minimum order is at least $60$.  But, how do you know there's not some other condition you're missing which actually bumps the minimum higher?  For example,a priori, there could have been some theorem like "Every group with an element of order 2 and 3 has one of order 345".  The way to rule out these kind of things is to construct an explicit example with $60$ elements, as jgon does.  In short, your argument gives a lower bound of $60$ whereas jgon's gives an upperbound of $60$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider $Z_{60}$, the cyclic group of order 60. If it is generated by $x$, then $x^0$ has order 1, $x^{30}$ has order 2, $x^{20}$ has order 3, $x^{15}$ has order 4, and $x^{12}$ has order 5. Note that by your argument, we know that the lcm of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 must divide the order of such a group, and since the lcm is 60, the minimum possible order is 60, and indeed, as we just showed, there is a group with this property of this order.

Comment: And this easily generalizes. If the list of required element orders is changed from $1,2,3,4,5$ into $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n$, then consider $r=\mathrm{lcm} (r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n)$. Then the answer must be at least $r$ because of the asker's own argument that the order of an element divides the order of the group. And also the answer must be _at most_ $r$ since the cyclic group $Z_r$ of order $r$ works. So the answer is exactly $r$.